# AES - High Iterations vs. Password Entropy

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

Hoping to get some clarification/understanding on an AES question, I'm new to crypto, so bear with me.

I have been tasked with encrypting data for a client.  I have written a c# class using `RijndaelManaged` and `SHA256` for the password hash based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt) I found here on Stack Overflow.  I'm using random 4-byte salt values along with static 8-byte salt values appended to the original data pre-encryption.

I've opted to go for AES 128-bit encryption, since 256-bit is considerably slower (~35% in my application), and overkill in this situation since its not terribly sensitive data (but our client is demanding it be encrypted at rest).  The next performance bottle neck appears to be the iterations, which I had at 1000.  In testing, encrypting 10K values took about 4 minutes, not terrible, but not great.  Reducing the iterations to 100, took it down to about 1.5 minutes.

Since speed is key, I'm looking for confirmation that if I'm using a massive 256 character (randomized; any letters/symbols) password from http://passwordsgenerator.net/, that I can safely reduce the iteration counter on the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Am I correct in that the iterations are primarily used to add entropy to low-entropy passwords?  Is reducing the iterations lower than 1000 (which seems to be the accepted threshold) doing more harm than good?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 256 *character* password, then it seems you have more than enough entropy for a key as it is. You would only need PBKDF2 with 1 iteration and a random >=8 byte salt. You can also use HKDF (not sure if there is a C# implementation) instead of PBKDF2. That's even more than enough entropy for AES-256.

**The issue that I see is that you used an online service to generate a password.** Don't do this. You cannot be certain that they don't sell the password they generated for you. Just generate a 32 byte master key with [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and encode it with Base64 to get a "password" that you can store in a string.

Comment: Thanks very much for the confirmation, I'll increase the random salt to 8 bytes.  I thank you for your concerns about the online service I hadn't considered that.  I'll disconnect from the web and use their client-side feature when I'm ready for a real password (so far we're just testing).  If that fails, I'll definitely follow your advise on the RNG.  Much appreciated.